# Valgrind understanding bytes allocated increase in heap summary?

Tags: c, valgrind

I have been looking at debugging the memory usage in a forking TCP server. I think I am doing pretty well, I just can't seem to find information on the 'bytes allocated' number in the 'heap summary'. This number seems to be ever increasing the longer my server runs:

```
==27526== 
==27526== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27526==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27526==   total heap usage: 113 allocs, 113 frees, 283,043 bytes allocated
==27526== 
==27526== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27526== 
==27526== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27526== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
==27528== 
==27528== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27528==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27528==   total heap usage: 120 allocs, 120 frees, 300,808 bytes allocated
==27528== 
==27528== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27528== 
==27528== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27528== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
==27537== 
==27537== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27537==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27537==   total heap usage: 127 allocs, 127 frees, 318,573 bytes allocated
==27537== 
==27537== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27537== 
==27537== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27537== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Although Valgrind reports allocs and free are equal and no leaks are possible I do not trust the allocated bytes increasing.

So : if the bytes allocated keeps increasing does this mean I have to deallocate from the heap somewhere even if Valgrind reports no leaks are possible?

Thanks!

EDIT:
With Gordon Bailey's answer and the other tips I am still a bit weary. Wrote this little app:

```
/* client.c */
#include <stdio.h>

void child_func(int childnum);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int nchildren = 1;
int pid;
int x;
if (argc > 1)
{
    nchildren = atoi(argv[1]);
}

for (x = 0; x < nchildren; x++)
{
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        child_func(x + 1);
        exit(0);
    }
}
wait(NULL);
return 0;
}

void child_func(int childnum)
{

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            free(malloc(1));
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

When I run this the Valgrind output is:

```
==28245== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28245==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28245==   total heap usage: 1,000 allocs, 1,000 frees, 1,000 bytes allocated
==28245== 
==28245== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28245== 
==28245== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28245== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
==28246== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28246==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28246==   total heap usage: 1,000 allocs, 1,000 frees, 1,000 bytes allocated
==28246== 
==28246== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

So it looks like all memory is cleared on the heap and is definitely different from the output of my app.

Comment: Do you have something in your server that is dependent on the history? Are the input to the program deterministic? If so, what happens if you give it the exact same input? Note that, input also consists of all files it opens.

Comment: Nope. The server accepts an incoming connect, forks itself to handle the connect, decodes the data and inserts into a Mysql database. After that I exit the fork and no data needs to be retained. I call exit on the fork, so it should in my opinion clear all data from heap.

Comment: It looks like it's just Valgrinds way of reporting total used memory over the course of the lifetime of the app (judging by the two answers below). I have no clue why I would want to know this, but such is life.

Comment: Well you _should_ certainly keep an eye on it. `valgrind` shouldn't be dependent on its own previous invocations. If your program really keeps getting ~7.8Kb more on each call, one day it will eventually run out of memory. My suggestion is to write a script that keeps doing this test, grep the `total heap usage` line and put it in a file. Run the script over night and in the morning you'll have a nice set of numbers to look at. If there was a pattern, you're in trouble.

Comment: Also, `valgrind` says _(suppressed: 2 from 2)_. Have you tried _For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: `-v`_?

Comment: Just tried valgrind -v ./myserver and get '--28368-- used_suppression:      2 dl-hack3-cond-1'. According to ' /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp' this is a generic condition : {
   dl-hack3-cond-1
   Memcheck:Cond   
   obj:/lib*/ld-2.15*.so*
   obj:/lib*/ld-2.15*.so*
   obj:/lib*/ld-2.15*.so*
}

Answer (score 3):

Valgrind's `bytes allocated` is the total number of bytes you've allocated over the runtime of the process.

If you compile and run this weird little test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
      free(malloc(1));
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Valgrind's output is:

```
==2651== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2651== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2651== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2651== Command: ./test_prog
==2651==
==2651==
==2651== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2651==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2651==   total heap usage: 1,000 allocs, 1,000 frees, 1,000 bytes allocated
==2651==
==2651== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2651==
==2651== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2651== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)
```

It seems like the real question now is how child processes affect this.

(edited to confirm what I thought)

Comment: I am getting `total heap usage: 1,001 allocs, 1,001 frees, 73,704 bytes allocated` i.e. one extra allocation. Do you know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is simply the sum of the sizes to all your malloc (and similar) calls. If you've free'd that, which valgrind says you have, there's no problem. i.e. your proces 27526 did 113 allocs for a total of 283,043 bytes,

If your server keeps allocating memory, that number goes up, calling free() does not decrease that number.

Answer (score 0):

as Godron said, valgrind output all memory allocation in the current process:

```
toc@UnixServer:~$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./pb_valgrind
==11411== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11411== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11411== Using Valgrind-3.6.1-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11411== Command: ./pb_valgrind
==11411== 
==11414== 
==11414== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11414==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11414==   total heap usage: 1,000 allocs, 1,000 frees, 1,000 bytes allocated
==11414== 
==11414== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11414== 
==11414== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11414== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
==11411== 
==11411== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11411==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11411==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==11411== 
==11411== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11411== 
==11411== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11411== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
```

In your program, you do 1000 mallocs of size 1 byte then 1000 free, which explain the output.

Regards.

Comment: Hi TOC, thanks for the help. The problem is that Valgrind reports the allocs and frees in my original application in the same quantity, however the bytes allocated keeps increasing.

Comment: @lleto : and what is the difference between difference runs? if you use Linux, you need to know that after fork the child process inherits all memory from his father (as read only) in the father memory space, and when he want to write this memory, the Kernel create a new copy on the child memory space and made it writable (this is what we call copy-on-write). So maybe that the environnement on difference runs are not the same!

Comment: when I run the application on each loop I have 6 more allocs (and frees). So the number of allocs and frees is the same in each loop, but overall the number increases. This causes Valgrind to correctly (I believe) report more heap mem used as it actually is. It is in my code, so I need to start searching there... thanks for your help.

Comment: @lleto Well, it's possible you allocate memory in your parent, that your child frees, but not the parent. So each time you fork(), the child has more memory(or a bigger array etc.) it loops through and frees. Either that or each of your childs simply have more work to do and use more memory which it subsequently frees, and there is no real problem.'

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when I run the application the number of frees and allocs increases each loop. This is causing the bytes allocated number to become bigger as each time the alloc actually assigns more memory as there are more actual allocs.

Not sure why that is happening, but it must be my buggy code and should be in another question.

Thanks for the help!