# mktime() reallocates heap memory when called

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I've been working on a c++ program and was having issues with heap memory allocations and leaks. I've fixed most of the leaks but I'm stuck on some allocations on the heap.

I'm using valgrind to find issues, when I exit my program it will print a heap summary, the one I'm working on is the "allocated", you can see it's 934,364 bytes, I will be optimizing later. Anyways I've been running different systems individually as after a day the "allocated memory" amount would go through the roof so I'm been trying to figure out what was causing that.

Turns out it was the time as that's updated every second, I was using localtime() but discovered it's not thread safe so switched to localtime_r() which stopped it from reallocating every read.

Thought I was golden but now I'm stuck on mktime(), it's doing the same but to a much lesser degree. This function is thread safe and I'm not finding much info related to memory on it. I tried free() on the struct but as expected that didn't help any.

Here's the functions I'm using.

```
struct tm result;
time_t t = time(NULL);
unsigned long long currentMillisTime = 0;
unsigned long long convertedMillis = 0;
short currentDay = 0;
short currentMonth = 0;
short currentYear = 0;
short currentWeekday = 0;

unsigned long long tmConvert_t(int YY, short MM, short DD, short hh, short mm, short ss) {
    result.tm_sec = ss;
    result.tm_min = mm;
    result.tm_hour = hh;
    result.tm_year = YY - 1900;
    result.tm_mon = MM;
    result.tm_mday = DD;
    convertedMillis = mktime(&result);
    convertedMillis = convertedMillis * 1000;
    return convertedMillis; 
}

void updateTime() {
    currentMillisTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();

    localtime_r(&t, &result);
    currentDay = result.tm_mday;  // 1-31
    currentMonth = result.tm_mon;  // 0 = January
    currentYear = result.tm_year + 1900;
    currentWeekday = result.tm_wday;  // 0 = Sunday
    
    midnightMillis = tmConvert_t(currentYear,currentMonth,currentDay,0,0,00);
}
```

When I run updateTime() every second the 934,364 bytes allocated will increase by 30 bytes each time forever. If I comment out the single line with "mktime()" this doesn't happen. I've suspended everything in the program so I know it's that line causing it, after the program starts nothing else is running and it clearly doesn't happen when that function isn't used. I don't know what to think.

This is the info from valgrind when I exit the program. This is running on a Raspberry Pi using g++ (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0.

```
==12111== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12111==     in use at exit: 72,685 bytes in 647 blocks
==12111==   total heap usage: 2,042 allocs, 1,395 frees, 934,364 bytes allocated
==12111==
==12111== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12111==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12111==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12111==      possibly lost: 504 bytes in 3 blocks
==12111==    still reachable: 72,181 bytes in 644 blocks
==12111==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12111== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

Thanks

Comment: Bytes allocated = sum of all calls to malloc/calloc and similar. It is not by itself a leak indication. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730265/valgrind-understanding-bytes-allocated-increase-in-heap-summary)

Comment: The "still reachable" line indicates leaks, memory that was allocated but never explicitly free'd before the program exited.

Comment: Thanks! So it's safe to say I can ignore that number and just worry about all 0's in leak summary? I've definitely noticed other functions, mine and c++ that keeps driving the allocated up so it does feel like just a counter. Would it be correct to say the program is using 72,685 bytes of memory? Originally I was thinking the "allocated" was how much the program was using. The program runs forever so nothing to free when it ends.